# Como recuperar os dados da sessão do CodeIgniter diretamente do banco de dados?

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, serialização, desserialização

Estou tentando recuperar dados da minha tabela `ci_sessions` do `CodeIgniter` que são salvos de forma serializada.

```
$data = $this->db->get_where('ci_sessions', array('id' => $id))->row('data');
var_dump(unserialize($data));
```

E obtenho esse erro:

```
// Message: unserialize(): Error at offset 0 of 135 bytes
```

Alguma forma de contornar isso?

Comment: Por que não utilizar a library de session do CodeIgniter para acessar os dados?

Comment: Porque desejo pegar os dados direto da tabela, transformar em array e fazer comparações. Não é apenas usar a sessão atual, quero recuperar antigas.

Comment: Mas na tabela você terá sempre a session mais atual de determinado cliente. As outras linhas são referentes a outras requisições. Você quer comparar os dados de clientes diferentes, é isso?

Comment: Na verdade, do mesmo, para poder informar pra ele, onde ele está logado.

Answer (score 1):

O que fiz uma vez foi pegar os dados da tabela `ci_session` onde `user_data` fosse diferente de vazio e listava esses dados, sei que não é bem o que procura, mas acho que já deve te dar uma luz.

```
$this->load->model('ci_sessions_model');
$data['all_results'] = $this->ci_sessions_model->get("user_data <> ''");

$this->load->view('widget_sessions', $data);
```

e na view eu listei as sessões ativas:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>IP ADDRESS</th>
            <th>USER AGENT</th>
            <th>LAST ACTIVITY</th>
            <th>USER DATA</th>                
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

    <?php
    foreach ($all_results as $all):
        $id_user = get_dados_user_data($all->user_data, array('id_user'));

        echo "\t\t<tr id='" . $all->session_id . "'>\n";
        echo "\t\t\t<td>" . $all->ip_address . "</td>\n";
        echo "\t\t\t<td>" . $all->user_agent . "</td>\n";
        echo "\t\t\t<td>" . get_timestamp_to_time($all->last_activity) . "</td>\n";
        echo "\t\t\t<td>" . get_dados_user_data($all->user_data, array('str_nome', 'str_sobrenome', 'str_email')) . "</td>\n";
        echo "\t\t</tr>\n";
    endforeach;
    ?>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

e tenho um `helper` para as funções `get_timestamp_to_time` e `get_dados_user_data`:

```
function get_timestamp_to_time($timestamp)
{
    if ($timestamp) {
        $date = new DateTime();
        $date->setTimestamp($timestamp);
        return $date->format('d/m/Y H:i:s');
    } else {
        return NULL;
    }
}

function get_dados_user_data($userdata, $valuesReturn = array())
{
    if ($userdata) {
        $ret = "";
        $arUserData = decode_user_data($userdata);
        foreach ($arUserData as $key => $value) {
            if (in_array($key, $valuesReturn)) {
                $ret.= $value . " ";
            }
        }
        return $ret;
    } 

    return NULL;      
}


function decode_user_data($userdata)
{
    if ($userdata) {
        return unserialize($userdata);
    }

    return NULL;     
}
```

Comment: muito boa resposta, mas o maior problema meu é que ao pegar os dados e dar um `unserialize()` o PHP me retorna um erro que diz que o formato dos dados em serial está errado e não faz a conversão. O CodeIgniter tem um jeito próprio de passar seus dados para `array`, mas também não tive sucesso em usar isso.

Comment: Mas me diz ai, vi que na sua chamada, fez um `where array('id' => $id))`, não entendi muito bem esse campo na sua tabela de sessão. E ainda assim, o que vem de resultado?

Comment: A sessão do CodeIgniter gera um cookie com um único valor: `id`, que é o id da sessão, o mesmo que fica salvo no DB e que o CI utiliza para restabelecer sessões. O meu resultado, se existir, é uma linha da tabela.

Comment: `get_where('ci_sessions', array('id' => $id) `
Corresponde à:
`SELECT * FROM ci_sessions WHERE id = '.$id.';`